# Rescale Image to Prevent Cropping

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a landing page with an image for a background.

```css
img {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_parallax.jpg"  />
</div>
```

On some mobile browsers, the image ends up getting cropped to much width-wise. I want to keep the full screen background image, but when I use `object-fit: contain` I lose the full screen effect.

Is there any way for me to rescale the image (while maintaining the aspect ratio) to reduce the amount of cropping on the left and right and after the page is rendered?

Comment: `object-fit: contain` will result in no cropping whatsoever

Comment: Well, you can't have 2 of them together at once. You need to either choose a better scalable image or use `object-fit: cover`. Otherwise, your image will be stretched.